# WebRtc on Windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, webrtc

I need to implement WebRtc on a windows phone 8.1 universal app,

there is some kind of library available?

I have found this one www.nuget.org/packages/WebRTC/1.1.24, but there isn't documentation.

thanks

Comment: This is not a good question for Stack Overflow. You are asking for an offsite tool or resource and not a specific technical programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IceLink claims to support that (commercial):

http://www.frozenmountain.com/webrtc/